# I need a function for excel to convert to camel case

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a function for excel which would convert

'random.text.random'

to

'randomTextRandom'

Comment: Try using `SUBSTITUTE` Function. Assuming the value is in cell A1 then the formula in cell B1 `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")`

Comment: Why not first character capitalized? It should be `RandomTextRandom`.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got to that answer when the output in the answer doesn’t match the output in your question. You said  very clearly and stated camel case but the answer doesn’t give you that. Some would think that this question was planted to provide reputation to a friend or colleague.

Comment: Absolutely I agree with you @Skin however I have no personal relation or not familiar with the person, but as per my understanding, OP has asked to convert or remove the dot irrespective of the case, which is not relevant here, may be some of your friend has challenged me let see who gets most votes which he has deleted as well after commenting below my answer, like you and the other person has got, but honestly there is no relation or anything. no personal gain,

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, he’s not my mate and as for the case, the OP has been clear with the expected output. I just find it weird is all. How you came to that conclusion baffles me given he said CAMEL CASE, which is a known industry standard. Case **does matter** and he never said anything about just getting rid of the periods. Anyway, well done on the rep. 

Comment: @Skin Sir, if you go with the OP's output, then I see VBasic2008 Sir, has given the proper solution as well, yeah, i came to the conclusion because i have given lot of same solution in FB, where members write like this and expect. May be OP's not aware of what Camel Case is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i have mentioned in comments above hence adding the same in the answers as well, also you can use Upper or Lower or Proper as per your requirement basically you needed to remove the dot and just concatenate without it

Formula used in cell B1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")
```

[image: SOLUTION]

Comment: Why is upper() relevant? That will make all the characters uppercase, not just the first one. Or will you be doing upper(left(A1)) and lower for the rest of the characters?

Comment: @SolarMike the query subject actually read as `I need a function for excel to convert to camel case` so i don't think the case is relevant here. If the case is relevant then OP should mention that as well, right!

Comment: You will find the Mods or a Mod deleted the comments - I have not added or removed any.

Comment: I deleted mine, since i thought @SolarMike Sir you deleted yours, where you have mentioned, that lets see who gets more votes. and i do have a screenshot as well!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your value is in cell **A1** ...

```
=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1)) & MID(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"."," "))," ",""),2,LEN(A1))
```

... or if you're expected to have the first character capitalized ...

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1)) & MID(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"."," "))," ",""),2,LEN(A1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below formula-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),".","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Convert to Camel Case

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)&SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))),".","") = randomTextRandom
```

- To the left of the first dot:

  ```
  LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1) = random
  ```
- To the right of the first dot:

  ```
  RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)) = text.random
  ```
- Make it proper:

  ```
  PROPER(...) = Text.Random
  ```
- Remove the remaining dot:

  ```
  SUBSTITUTE(...,".","") = TextRandom
  ```